# String and sscanf

Tags: c, tokenize, c-strings

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[] = "My first book";
    char *a, *b, *c;
    sscanf(str, "%s %s %s", a, b, c);
    printf("a=%s b=%s c=%s", a, b, c);
}
```

I want the output: a=My b=first and c=book. I am getting seg fault. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialised `a`, `b` and `c`

So do this

```
char a[100], b[100], c[100]
```

Also you need to check the return value from `sscanf` - Please check out the manual page

The  format string is incorrect it should be

```
 "%[^ ] %[^ ] %[^ ]"
```

Details are also on the manual page

[sscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf)

**EDIT**

If you do not know the length of the string then do

```
char *a, *b, *c;
size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
a = malloc(len);
b = malloc(len);
c = malloc(len);

...

free(a);
free(b):
free(c);
```

Comment: I do not know the length of the string

Answer (score 1):

The pointers

```
char *a,*b,*c;
```

are uninitialized and have indeterminate value. So this call of sscanf

```
sscanf(str,"%s %s %s",a,b,c);
```

has undefined behavior.

Instead you could use the standard function `strtok` to split the character array `str` into tokens.

For example if you are sure that the array contains at least three words then you can write

```
a = strtok( str, " " );
b = strtok( NULL, " " );
c = strtok( NULL, " " );
```

and then

```
printf("a=%s b=%s c=%s",a,b,c);
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char str[] = "My first book";

    char *a, *b, *c;

    a = strtok( str,  " " );
    b = strtok( NULL, " " );
    c = strtok( NULL, " " );

    printf("a=%s b=%s c=%s\n", a, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
a=My b=first c=book
```

Comment: If I am not sure what can I do?

Comment: @anonim I am sorry. I have not understood the question.

Comment: @anonim If in a string there are less tokens than you are expecting then you should check the returned value of the function to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting segfault because `a`, `b` and `c` are pointers that aren't initialized. When using pointers you need to allocate memory for them. For your simple example you can get away with on the stack allocations by declaring your strings as `char a[100]`. The compiler will allocate the size for 100 characters and if the string isn't larger than that (and in this particular example it isn't) then you should be fine.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "My first book";
    char a[3], b[6], c[5];
    sscanf(str, "%s %s %s", a, b, c);
    printf("a=%s b=%s c=%s", a, b, c);
}
```

Because you know exactly what your strings are then you can declare the variables with the exact size of the words (+1 for the null terminating character).

And the version with dynamic memory allocation.

```c
int main()
{
    char str[] = "My first book";
    char *a, *b, *c;
    a = (char *)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
    b = (char *)malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
    c = (char *)malloc(5 * sizeof(char));

    // when allocating memory dinamically it is good practice to check for null
    if (a == NULL || b == NULL || c == NULL) {
        printf("bad allocation!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    sscanf(str, "%s %s %s", a, b, c);
    printf("a=%s b=%s c=%s", a, b, c);
}
```